# Прокрутка колесиком в Chrome и Opera

Tags: html, css, кроссбраузерность

Здравствуйте. Не работает вертикальная прокрутка на моем разрабатываемом сайте, именно колесиком в Chrome и Opera (версии самые новые), остальными методами всё без нареканий. В Mozilla работает всё включая пролистывание колесом мыши. Что это может быть? Много где искал решение, многое испробовал, в коде искал ошибки... Ни в какую.

Comment: Не работает на всех сайтах? На вашей странице? Пока что это очень общий вопрос и вероятно даже, что не о веб-разработке вообще, исправьте как можно быстрее.